# Replace third column on all rows of a file in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file that has about 60 columns of data. The file is also about 80 million records long. I need a bash command to replace the third column with '20190113'. How do we determine it is the third column? It is delimited by the non-printable character '\001'

So replace the third field on all records of data in a file delimited by the special character '\001' with the value '20190113;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` can handle non-printing characters, including `\001`.

```
$ cat -v test.in
abc^Axyz^Afoo
def^Awvu^Abar
$ awk '{$3 = "20190113"}1' FS=$'\1' OFS=$'\1' test.in | cat -v
abc^Axyz^A20190113
def^Awvu^A20190113
```

`$'…'` is a construction supported by most shells that lets you use escape characters.
`^A` represents the `\001` character; `-v` tells `cat` to print that instead of a literal non-printing `\001` byte.

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as `awk`, but here is method with `sed`.

```
a=$(printf "1\0012\0013\0014\0015")
# check
echo "$a" | hexdump -c
b=$(echo "$a" | sed -r 's/([^\x01]*\x01[^\x01]*\x01)[^\x01]*[^x01]/\120190113\x01/')
# check
echo "$b" | hexdump -c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hex format "\xdd" to specify the delimiters for awk.
Just set the Input and Output delimiters in the BEGIN section.

```
$ cat -v brian.txt
abc^Axyz^Afoo
def^Awvu^Abar

$ awk ' BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\x01"} { $3="20190113"; print } ' brian.txt
abcxyz20190113
defwvu20190113

$ awk ' BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\x01"} { $3="20190113"; print } ' brian.txt | cat -v
abc^Axyz^A20190113
def^Awvu^A20190113

$
```

You can try with Perl also

```
$ perl -F"\x01" -lane ' $F[2]="20190113"; print join("\x01",@F) ' brian.txt
abcxyz20190113
defwvu20190113

$ perl -F"\x01" -lane ' $F[2]="20190113"; print join("\x01",@F) ' brian.txt | cat -v
abc^Axyz^A20190113
def^Awvu^A20190113

$
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^[.\d1.]]*/20190113/3' file
```

This replaces the third occurrence of those characters that do not match `\001` with the string `20190113` on every line throughout the file.